# C# : How to set value an item in an array inside of a dynamic object?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, object

```cs
object result = new
{
    items = new[] {
        new {name = "command" , index = "X", optional = "0"},
        new {name = "command" , index = "X", optional = "0"}
    }
};
```

I would like to change the first item's name property's value from "command" to "XYZ".

The following doesn't work. What is the right way?

```
result.GetType().GetProperties()[0].GetType().GetProperty("Name").SetValue(result,"XYZ")
```

Error:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Property set method not found.'
```

Comment: Debug your code and find out what part exactly "does not work". Is there an exception or `null` value being returned in that call chain? Find out where. Fix it. Try again. This is a part of the debugging process that *every* developer goes through.

Comment: Anonymous type properties are read only and they cannot be set.

Comment: Create strongly-typed classes and let the compiler check correctness so you don't have to.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted more detail instead of "The following doesn't work". You must be getting an error so what does the error say?

Comment: I have added the error.

Comment: In recent versions of C#, you could use a `record` to encapsulate a simple class like this. You could even make it mutable if you're so inclined. Note that anonymous types, while easy to declare on the fly, are not in any way "dynamic" -- they have a fixed structure, just not a name.

Comment: @DourHighArch that is not in my control. My piece of code will receive object. And there is nothing I can change in external code.

Comment: Object that I receive can either be dynamic or some variant of it such as expandoObject. But it can not be strongly typed. There are certain things that are just not in your control.

Comment: @Klamsi so there is absolutely no way to do this? Given that the data type of the result could only be object or some variant of it like expandoobject?

Comment: The simple fact is this: if you receive a type with properties that cannot be set (such as an anonymous type) then you cannot set its properties. That, too, is not under your control. You may be trying to get a use case to work that's just not relevant -- anonymous types are not `ExpandoObject`s.

Comment: @JeroenMostert anonymous types indeed have a name (assigned by the compiler), e.g. `var foo = new { Bar = 1 };
Console.WriteLine(foo.GetType().FullName);` outputs <>f__AnonymousType0`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]] with my runtime.

Comment: @JeroenMostert even if i am willing to create a new object from the `result`?

Comment: @EricJ.: yes, obviously. They are "anonymous" because they have no name you can use *at compile time*. Every CLR type does have a name, no doubt about that.

Comment: @SamuraiJack: There seem to be Hacks, that you can change properties but as I understood it depends on compiler internals. What about going the way with Newtonsoft JSON and creating a new object?

Comment: @SamuraiJack: if you are at liberty to create a new object, you *could* do it, by invoking the type's generated constructor (and passing it the current value of all properties, save the one you're changing). But to do this reliably, you would need to know you're dealing with an anonymous type, since you cannot generally count on a specific constructor to assign fields in order. This is fairly hacky.

Comment: @SamuraiJack - Please check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that Anonymous type properties are read only and they cannot be set. However, you could convert the `Anonymous types` to `ExpandoObject`:

Custom `ToExpando` method:

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static IEnumerable<dynamic> ToExpando(this IEnumerable<object> anonymousObject)
    {
        IList<dynamic> list = new List<dynamic>();

        foreach (var item in anonymousObject)
        {
            IDictionary<string, object> anonymousDictionary = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(item);
            IDictionary<string, object> expando = new ExpandoObject();

            foreach (var nestedItem in anonymousDictionary)
                expando.Add(nestedItem);

            list.Add(expando);
        }

        return list.AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

Modify anonymous type value:

```
//change object to var...
var result = new
{
    items = new[] {
        new {name = "command" , index = "X", optional = "0"},
        new {name = "command" , index = "X", optional = "0"}
    }
};
var data = result.items.ToExpando().ToList();

//modify the value of name property
data.First().name = "XYZ";
```

Answer (score 0):

1. result variable's type is declared as object
2. but value assigned to it is anonymous type
3. So result becomes anonymous type & hence its values can not be modified & same you would get if you change result variable type from object to var.
4. & since result variable becomes anonymous type, you would not be able to modify its property values & hence error is on same lines i.e. System.ArgumentException: 'Property set method not found.'.